# Best file structure for home server?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Okay, I have a home server running Ubuntu Server and I use it as a file server, media server, seedbox, game server, and web server. Previously I just installed everything to the root folder and I know that's not very secure or conventional. My brand new hard drive just arrived (was running out of storage) so I decided to now organize my file structure. I want to keep my existing installation of Ubuntu Server and mount the new hard drive elsewhere.

Where should I mount the new hard drive and where should I move all of my data and programs? I've read tutorials where they create separate users for each application - don't know if that makes everything easier - but I don't really know where I should move everything too. Suggestions?

Comment: Would suggest using LVM, it would limit apps to certain sizes in particular volumes, which can be increased on need basis by single command. Critical apps should have always enough space.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer will depend on the size of the drive and the amount of data you expect in each category.

However, if it is only one additional hard drive that you are using, I would not partition it too much as the more you partition it the more limitation you may have in the long run.  That is, you may decide that the new physical drive with 1TB will have 500 GB for movies, 300 GB for games, and 200 GB for music.  You may end up using more for movies and less in music leading to having to resize partitions.  This may take some time if there is lots of data in the partitions you are resizing (which is often the case as resizing is often done when one runs out of space).

I would separate the anything accessed from outside your local network into a separate partition.

As for the exact mapping location, and based on the above you can use /data (with folder separating the type of data) and /www.